# Azure Data Factory Relative URL No Longer Working

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am currently making request calls to a API using the HTTP Service Link.

[image]

I am trying to add the following relative url
@concat('https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/', dataset().companyId, '/financials.json')

[image]

The actual link service looks like the following:

[image]

I was getting the error

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=HttpInvalidUrlAddress,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http Url Address 'https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/02690345/financials.json' is invalid.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy dueREST to ADLS",
    "details": []
}
```

I removed

@concat('https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/', dataset().companyId, '/financials.json')

But whenever I now try to enter anything into the relative URL I get nothing, meaning if I were to add something meaningless like 'myrelativeurl'

I would just get

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithUnauthorizedError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http request failed with status code 401 Unauthorized, usually this is caused by invalid credentials, please check your activity settings.\nRequest URL: https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.,Source=System,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy dueREST to ADLS",
    "details": []
```

But I would expect an error with at least the following:

**https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/myrelativeurl**

Can someone let me know why the relative url is suddenly not appearing at all?

I tested the connection with single copy activity and it worked fine with the following as source and sink

[image]

You will notice here that I have included the full base url (no relative url)

[image]

And once again the HTTP Link Service looks like the following

[image]

When I use this single copy activity it works fine.

Comment: Is the copy data running successfully without any relative URL with the `X-AUTH-TOKEN` auth header?

Comment: Good question Saideep, let me check

Comment: Hi Saideep, I have just updated the question, which I think answers your question

Comment: Can you confirm this: You want to call this URL `https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/<dataset().companyId value>/financials.json`

Comment: can you try giving the relative URL as `@concat(dataset().companyId, '/financials.json')`

Comment: I tried that but was still getting nothing after https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/ . I will try again

Comment: Hi Saideep, I gave the relative URL as you suggested, but the problem is that it's even trying to add the relative URL... ```{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithUnauthorizedError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Message=Http request failed with status code 401 Unauthorized, usually this is caused by invalid credentials, \nRequest URL: https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/.
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy dueREST to ADLS",
    "details": []
}```

Comment: If it even added something, I could troubleshoot...

Comment: This might be the indication that the connection itself has some issue i.e., with credentials. You said that URL while using single copy works. Is `06999618.json?` the relative URL you are trying to create dynamically in the dataset?

Comment: Hi Saideep, I'm not sure the issue is with the credentials. I have managed to get it before. In any case, I should see something after https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/ correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248639/discussion-between-saideep-arikontham-and-patterson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove *'https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/',* from the concat in the first example